# Java incrementing every character in a string by a large amount?

Tags: java, loops

Currently I have a program that asks for a string, for example "Hello stackoverflow!" and I'm trying to make it increment every individual character by a large, random number. The problem is, once the program gets to `'~'` it has to start going backwards, then once it gets `'!'` it has to switch again. (`!` is the first Ascii symbol, and `~` is the last, with numbers and letters in the middle.) So far this is what I have for the incrementing part, it isn't quite working though:

```
for(int i = 0; i < inputStringB.length(); i++){
    currentChar = inputString.charAt(i);

    for(int e = 0; e < 1000; e++){

        if(currentChar == '!'){
            switchIncrement = 1;
        } else if(currentChar == '~') {
            switchIncrement = 0;
        }

        switch(switchInc){
            case 0: currentChar--;
                inputStringB.setCharAt(i, currentChar);
                break;
            case 1: currentChar++;
                inputStringB.setCharAt(i, currentChar);
                break;
            default:  currentChar++;
                inputStringB.setCharAt(i, currentChar);
                break;
        }
    }               
    System.out.println(inputStringB);   
}
```

When I input `'Hello'` I receive: `'n#J&)'` Which doesn't make sense considering `'Hello'` contains two `l`'s, so I would expect `'n#JJ)'`

Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Full code:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
public class EncryptionMain {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        char currentChar;
        String EorD;
        int switchInc = 1; // 0 = BACK 1 = FORWARD 
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Encrypt or decrypt: ");

        EorD = scanner.next();

        if(EorD.equalsIgnoreCase("e")){

            System.out.println("Please enter text to encrypt: ");

            String inputString = scanner.next();

            System.out.println("Encrypting: '" + inputString + "' ");
            System.out.println("...");
            System.out.println("...");
            System.out.println("...");
            StringBuilder inputStringB = new StringBuilder(inputString);
            for(int i = 0; i < inputStringB.length(); i++){
                currentChar = inputStringB.charAt(i);
                System.out.println(currentChar);
                for(int e = 0; e < 1000; e++){

                        if(currentChar == '!'){
                            switchInc = 1;
                        }else if(currentChar == '~'){
                            switchInc = 0;
                        }

                        switch(switchInc){

                        case 0: currentChar--;
                                inputStringB.setCharAt(i, currentChar);
                                break;

                        default:  currentChar++;
                                  inputStringB.setCharAt(i, currentChar);
                                  break;
                        }
                }

                System.out.println(inputStringB);   
            }
        }else if(EorD.equalsIgnoreCase("d")){

            System.out.println("Please enter text to decrypt: ");

            String inputString = scanner.next();

            System.out.println("Decrypting: '" + inputString + "' ");
            System.out.println("...");
            System.out.println("...");
            System.out.println("...");
            StringBuilder inputStringB = new StringBuilder(inputString);
            for(int i = 0; i < inputStringB.length(); i++){
                currentChar = inputStringB.charAt(i);

                for(int e = 0; e < 1000; e++){
                    if(currentChar == '!'){
                            switchInc = 0;
                    }else if(currentChar == '~'){
                            switchInc = 1;
                    }
                        switch(switchInc){
                        case 0: currentChar++;
                                inputStringB.setCharAt(i, currentChar);
                                break;
                        case 1: currentChar--;
                                inputStringB.setCharAt(i, currentChar);
                                break;
                        default:  currentChar--;
                                  inputStringB.setCharAt(i, currentChar);
                                  break;
                        }
                }

                inputStringB.setCharAt(i, currentChar);
                System.out.println(inputStringB);   
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So what have you done to debug it?

Comment: Your case 1 is unneeded. The default does the same thing and without the explicit 1 case it would catch that.

Comment: Where does the "random number" come in? I don't see any randomness in the code you've given.

Comment: @ChrisMartin I'm planning on adding that once I fix the main issue, I probably shouldn't have said that.

Comment: It would help to post compiling code. All of these variables are undeclared: `inputStringB`, `inputString`, `currentChar`, `switchIncrement`, `switchInc`.

Comment: @ChrisMartin I posted the entire code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'm going to remove all of the I/O (except for outputting the result), get rid of the decryption piece for brevity, and write `encrypt(String)` and `encrypt(char)` as [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).

```
public class EncryptionMain {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(encrypt("Hello"));
    }

    static String encrypt(String plaintext) {
        StringBuilder ciphertext = new StringBuilder(plaintext);
        for (int i = 0; i < ciphertext.length(); i++) {
            ciphertext.setCharAt(i, encrypt(ciphertext.charAt(i)));
        }
        return ciphertext.toString();
    }

    static char encrypt(char c) {
        int switchInc = 1; // 0 = BACK 1 = FORWARD

        for(int e = 0; e < 1000; e++){
            if (c == '!') {
                switchInc = 1;
            } else if (c == '~') {
                switchInc = 0;
            }

            switch (switchInc) {
                case 0: c--; break;
                default: c++; break;
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

And, whoops! - just by doing that, I accidentally fixed the bug. Here, I'll add it back:

```
public class EncryptionMain {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(encrypt("Hello"));
    }

    static String encrypt(String plaintext) {
        StringBuilder ciphertext = new StringBuilder(plaintext);
        for (int i = 0; i < ciphertext.length(); i++) {
            ciphertext.setCharAt(i, encrypt(ciphertext.charAt(i)));
        }
        return ciphertext.toString();
    }

    static int switchInc = 1; // 0 = BACK 1 = FORWARD

    static char encrypt(char c) {

        for(int e = 0; e < 1000; e++){
            if (c == '!') {
                switchInc = 1;
            } else if (c == '~') {
                switchInc = 0;
            }

            switch (switchInc) {
                case 0: c--; break;
                default: c++; break;
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

---

Edit - Here's a working Caesar cipher I referred to in the comments below.

*main/cipher/Cipher.java*

```
package cipher;

public final class Cipher {

    public Cipher(Range range, int key) {
        this.range = range;
        this.key = key;
    }

    public final Range range;
    public final int key;

    public String encrypt(String plaintext) {
        return cipher(plaintext, key);
    }

    public String decrypt(String ciphertext) {
        return cipher(ciphertext, -key);
    }

    String cipher(String in, int n) {
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(in.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {
            out.append(range.shift(in.charAt(i), n));
        }
        return out.toString();
    }
}
```

*main/cipher/Range.java*

```
package cipher;

public final class Range {

    public final char min;
    public final char max;
    public final int size;

    public static Range inclusive(char min, char max) {
        return new Range(min, max);
    }

    Range(char min, char max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        size = max - min + 1;
    }

    /** Shift c up by i places, wrapping around to the
     * beginning of the range when it reaches the end. */
    public char shift(char c, int i) {
        return (char) (min + mod(c - min + i, size));
    }

    /** x mod a */
    static int mod(int x, int a) {
        return ((x % a) + a) % a;
    }
}
```

*test/cipher/CipherTest.java*

```
package cipher;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;

public class CipherTest {

    @Test
    public void testZeroKey() throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = new Cipher(Range.inclusive('a', 'z'), 0);
        assertEquals(cipher.encrypt("abcxyz"), "abcxyz");
        assertEquals(cipher.decrypt("abcxyz"), "abcxyz");
    }

    @Test
    public void testOneKey() throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = new Cipher(Range.inclusive('a', 'z'), 1);
        assertEquals(cipher.encrypt("abcxyz"), "bcdyza");
        assertEquals(cipher.decrypt("bcdyza"), "abcxyz");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSizePlusOneKey() throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = new Cipher(Range.inclusive('a', 'z'), 27);
        assertEquals(cipher.encrypt("abcxyz"), "bcdyza");
        assertEquals(cipher.decrypt("bcdyza"), "abcxyz");
    }
}
```

*test/cipher/RangeTest.java*

```
package cipher;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;
import static cipher.Range.mod;

public class RangeTest {

    @Test
    public void testSize() {
        Assert.assertEquals(Range.inclusive('a', 'c').size, 3);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMod() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(mod(-2, 5), 3);
        assertEquals(mod(-1, 5), 4);
        assertEquals(mod(0, 5), 0);
        assertEquals(mod(1, 5), 1);
        assertEquals(mod(2, 5), 2);
        assertEquals(mod(3, 5), 3);
        assertEquals(mod(4, 5), 4);
        assertEquals(mod(5, 5), 0);
        assertEquals(mod(6, 5), 1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testShift() throws Exception {
        Range r = Range.inclusive('a', 'd');
        Assert.assertEquals(r.shift('a', -2), 'c');
        Assert.assertEquals(r.shift('a', -1), 'd');
        Assert.assertEquals(r.shift('a', 0), 'a');
        Assert.assertEquals(r.shift('a', 1), 'b');
        Assert.assertEquals(r.shift('a', 2), 'c');
        Assert.assertEquals(r.shift('a', 3), 'd');
        Assert.assertEquals(r.shift('a', 4), 'a');
        Assert.assertEquals(r.shift('a', 5), 'b');
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I learn so much just by asking a question, love this site. But can you tell me what was wrong with my code? I still can't tell.

Comment: And I noticed one more thing, if you have a large number in the for loop with, "int e = 0; e < 1000..." the program doesn't work.

Comment: Look carefully at the difference between the two versions in my answer. The difference is the scope of `switchInc`. That variable needs to be initialized to `1` every time you encrypt a character. You can't share the variable and just use whatever value it had left over from the previous iteration.

Comment: Be more specific about what "doesn't work" means? It seems fine (though grossly inefficient) to me.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't specific I was in a rush. What I meant was if I encrypt: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%^&*()`~-_=+[{]};':",./<>?|\" I get an output of: "UTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA@?>=<wxyz{|}~}vgvijkXlpnoV8sWyq[;Y9{m|hrtuzxw:Z" Which doesn't make sense, because in the encrypted string there are repeating characters, such as "{, and |"

Comment: Yes, the encryption function you've defined isn't injective. Try a simpler example: Change `!` and `~` to `0` and `9`, and change `1000` to `5`. If you encrypt `"35"`, the output is `"88"`. This means it's lossy (impossible to decrypt).

Comment: Does that mean I would have to rewrite my code for that problem to be fixed? Or is this just unsolvable?

Comment: You have correctly coded the algorithm you described, but the algorithm you described isn't reversible. It seems like maybe what you really want is a Caesar cipher, in which case this would do the trick: `static char encrypt(char c) { return (char) ('!' + (c - '!' + 1000) % ('~' - '!' + 1)); }`

Comment: And for decrypting it?

Comment: For decryption, subtract 1000 instead of adding, and replace use mod instead of remainder. I'll update my answer with code.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, but what exactly did you mean by "replace use mod instead of remainder" what's the difference?

Comment: Sorry, meant to just write "use mod instead of remainder". Java's `%` is the remainder operator, which is similar to mod, except it returns a negative result if the first operand is negative. Mod n, in contrast, always returns a nonnegative result between 0 and n-1.

Comment: Now the last thing before I declare this project finished is to fix the issue where it stops after the first word, in other words, it only encrypts/decrypts the first word then stops there. I tried this, but it didn't change the output:     static char encrypt(char c) { if(c == ' '){ return (' '); }else{ return (char) ('!' + (c - '!' + 5) % ('~' - '!' + 1)); }}

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you write a failing test case for it?

Comment: Well, if I try to encrypt "Hello world!" it returns "mjqqt" not "mjqqt |twqi" , mjqqt being the encrypted version of hello.

Comment: I think I just found the problem "ciphertext.length()" stops counting after the first word, meaning it has a value of 5 (hello is 5 characters long.) I'm not sure why its returning 5 instead of the whole string's length.

Comment: I solved the problem, I was using "scanner.next();" instead of "scanner.nextLine();" The program is finished! Thank you very much for your help!